# Django Static Precompiler for LESS

Tags: python, django, less

I'm using this - https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/django-static-precompiler and everything seems to work just fine, but I've got one question. Does the compilation of less file occur every time the template with less is used? Or is there some kind of caching? I'm asking because less file can be rather big and if every time a user makes a request less compilation occurs that's really frustrating.

Comment: This is explained in the README of the package...

Answer (score 0):

at https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/django-static-precompiler, you can read:

```
    STATIC_PRECOMPILER_USE_CACHE
    Whether to use cache for inline compilation. Default: True.
    STATIC_PRECOMPILER_CACHE_TIMEOUT
    Cache timeout for inline styles (in seconds). Default: 30 days.
    STATIC_PRECOMPILER_MTIME_DELAY
    Cache timeout for reading the modification time of source files (in seconds). Default: 10 seconds.
    STATIC_PRECOMPILER_CACHE_NAME
    Name of the cache to be used. If not specified then the default django cache is used. Default: None.
```

Comment: Isn't this about inline less?

Comment: There is no such thing as inline Less. Or i do not understand what you mean.  You can compile Less on the command line (server side) http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage or in browser (client side) both methods compile your Less into (static) CSS code. As far as i understand the django compiler compiles your Less server side.